# Accessing family sharing members info

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Is there a way to access "ios 8 family sharing" members information from an app?. I am working on an app that shares information between family members, and this could be a way to determine who access what information.

Answer (score 1):

CloudKit does not give that option today.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I know CloudKit does not have that option, I am looking for any way to access that information.